# How to change position of an imagebutton with a background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following view and want to change the postion of the door so that it has a bit padding to the top. But the padding top attribute does not change anything in my view. What can that be?

Here is my view

http://pbrd.co/UV4YsY

And the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/attach_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logout"
            android:onClick="logoutAction"
            android:paddingTop="100dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_blau"
            android:onClick="startSettingsAction"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/furst"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="left"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sec"
        android:onClick="logoutAction"
        android:paddingTop="100dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/thir"
        android:onClick="startSettingsAction" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]